# Angular 12: SSR does not getting translate files path

Tags: angular, internationalization, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, absolute-path

I have angular project in which I have file(src->app->lang-translate->lang-translate.module.ts) which is accessing files of other location like below.

```
{prefix: "../../assets/translate/Pages/header/", suffix: ".json"},
{prefix: "../../assets/translate/Pages/footer/", suffix: ".json"},
```

I am getting error like below when I used SSR in this angular project

```
Could not find translation file: ../../assets/translate/Pages/header/en.json

Could not find translation file: ../../assets/translate/Pages/footer/en.json
```

So I need to try absolute path for files but not getting how.
I have tried [this](https://jacobneterer.medium.com/import-via-absolute-paths-in-angular-fc4146bf2330) but getting same error

How I can get absolute path of those files which will be common for both local and production in angular?
Is there any way I can know absolute path of file in angular?

or

how I can let know SSR the paths of translate files?

Comment: Have you added your paths in config file?

Comment: @SnehaPawar how? I am new to angular. so don't know much of it. How can I check that?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more here? which service you want to inject just post some code so i can get better understanding

Comment: @SnehaPawar pls check.

Comment: Have you added TranslateModule in app.module.ts file?

Comment: @SnehaPawar yes

Comment: try updating your path to {prefix: "./src/assets/translate/Pages/footer/", suffix: ".json"},

Comment: @SnehaPawar still getting same error :(

Answer (score 0):

I use `@ngx-translate`. In the [`app.browser.module.ts`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/app/app.browser.module.ts) I import the `TranslateHttpLoader`, in the [`app.server.module.ts`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/app/app.server.module.ts) I use the `TranslateJsonLoader`. This works without relying on silly string-filepaths.

Comment: Hi, could you please guide me to article or documentation (you referred) that needs to be follow for applying internationalization in SSR project?